# How to keep out from the sum calculation the negative variables?

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), rnum = c(-2,0,3,2)
```

How is it possible to use the sum(df$rnum) and receive the 5 result ignoring the negative values
?

Comment: `sum(df$rnum * (df$rnum >= 0))` or `sum(df$rnum[df$rnum >= 0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset only the positive values and take `sum` -

```
sum(df$rnum[df$rnum > 0])
#[1] 5
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the number of rows which don't have the negative value?

Comment: You can use `subset` - `subset(df, rnum >= 0)`

Comment: I think this is a subset for the whole data frame. Mayber nrow could work?

Comment: Do you want to count the number of rows ? `nrow(subset(df, rnum >= 0))`

Answer (score 3):

We could also use:

```
sum(df[df$rnum > 0,]$rnum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
sum(subset(df, rnum > 0, select = rnum)[[1]])
```